# Spring boot Binding to cloudmaqp error when deployed on heroku

Tags: spring-boot, heroku, spring-cloud-stream, spring-rabbit, cloudamqp

I have one service deployed to heroku. my service use cloudamqp as cloud messagging service. when my service running on my local env i connection is success and i never found this error.

but when i deploy my service to heroku, i got this error.

```
2017-10-30T06:03:05.231416+00:00 app[web.1]: 2017-10-30 06:03:05.231  INFO 4 --- [freshExecutor-0] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient    : Getting all instance registry info from the eureka server
2017-10-30T06:03:05.256787+00:00 app[web.1]: 2017-10-30 06:03:05.256  INFO 4 --- [freshExecutor-0] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient    : The response status is 200
2017-10-30T06:03:07.002922+00:00 app[web.1]: 2017-10-30 06:03:07.002  WARN 4 --- [nfoReplicator-0] o.s.b.a.health.RabbitHealthIndicator     : Health check failed
2017-10-30T06:03:07.002970+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2017-10-30T06:03:07.002971+00:00 app[web.1]: org.springframework.amqp.AmqpConnectException: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
2017-10-30T06:03:07.002972+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.support.RabbitExceptionTranslator.convertRabbitAccessException(RabbitExceptionTranslator.java:62)
2017-10-30T06:03:07.002972+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.AbstractConnectionFactory.createBareConnection(AbstractConnectionFactory.java:368)
2017-10-30T06:03:07.002973+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.CachingConnectionFactory.createConnection(CachingConnectionFactory.java:573)
2017-10-30T06:03:07.002974+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitTemplate.doExecute(RabbitTemplate.java:1430)
2017-10-30T06:03:07.002974+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitTemplate.execute(RabbitTemplate.java:1411)
2017-10-30T06:03:07.002975+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitTemplate.execute(RabbitTemplate.java:1387)
2017-10-30T06:03:07.002976+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.health.RabbitHealthIndicator.getVersion(RabbitHealthIndicator.java:49)
2017-10-30T06:03:07.002976+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.health.RabbitHealthIndicator.doHealthCheck(RabbitHealthIndicator.java:45)
2017-10-30T06:03:07.002977+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.health.AbstractHealthIndicator.health(AbstractHealthIndicator.java:43)
2017-10-30T06:03:07.002977+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.health.CompositeHealthIndicator.health(CompositeHealthIndicator.java:68)
2017-10-30T06:03:07.002978+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.EurekaHealthCheckHandler.getHealthStatus(EurekaHealthCheckHandler.java:103)
2017-10-30T06:03:07.002978+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.EurekaHealthCheckHandler.getStatus(EurekaHealthCheckHandler.java:99)
2017-10-30T06:03:07.002978+00:00 app[web.1]:    at com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient.refreshInstanceInfo(DiscoveryClient.java:1362)
2017-10-30T06:03:07.002979+00:00 app[web.1]:    at com.netflix.discovery.InstanceInfoReplicator.run(InstanceInfoReplicator.java:100)
2017-10-30T06:03:07.002980+00:00 app[web.1]:    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
2017-10-30T06:03:07.002980+00:00 app[web.1]:    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
2017-10-30T06:03:07.002981+00:00 app[web.1]:    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
2017-10-30T06:03:07.002981+00:00 app[web.1]:    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293)
2017-10-30T06:03:07.002982+00:00 app[web.1]:    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
2017-10-30T06:03:07.002983+00:00 app[web.1]:    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
2017-10-30T06:03:07.002983+00:00 app[web.1]:    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
2017-10-30T06:03:07.002984+00:00 app[web.1]: Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
2017-10-30T06:03:07.002985+00:00 app[web.1]:    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
2017-10-30T06:03:07.002985+00:00 app[web.1]:    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)
2017-10-30T06:03:07.002986+00:00 app[web.1]:    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
2017-10-30T06:03:07.002987+00:00 app[web.1]:    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
2017-10-30T06:03:07.002987+00:00 app[web.1]:    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
2017-10-30T06:03:07.002988+00:00 app[web.1]:    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
2017-10-30T06:03:07.002989+00:00 app[web.1]:    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.SocketFrameHandlerFactory.create(SocketFrameHandlerFactory.java:50)
2017-10-30T06:03:07.002989+00:00 app[web.1]:    at com.rabbitmq.client.ConnectionFactory.newConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:907)
2017-10-30T06:03:07.002990+00:00 app[web.1]:    at com.rabbitmq.client.ConnectionFactory.newConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:859)
2017-10-30T06:03:07.002990+00:00 app[web.1]:    at com.rabbitmq.client.ConnectionFactory.newConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:799)
2017-10-30T06:03:07.002991+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.AbstractConnectionFactory.createBareConnection(AbstractConnectionFactory.java:352)
2017-10-30T06:03:07.002992+00:00 app[web.1]:    ... 19 common frames omitted
2017-10-30T06:03:07.002993+00:00 app[web.1]:
```

when i see my rabbitmq management page, my service succesfully connect to my cloudamqp rabbitmq server. shown like this

[image: CloudAmqp RabbitMq Manager Page]

this is my application.yml on my services..

```
spring:
    application:
        name: filehandler
    jackson:
        serialization.write_dates_as_timestamps: false
    jpa:
        open-in-view: false
        hibernate:
            ddl-auto: update
            naming:
                physical-strategy: org.springframework.boot.orm.jpa.hibernate.SpringPhysicalNamingStrategy
                implicit-strategy: org.springframework.boot.orm.jpa.hibernate.SpringImplicitNamingStrategy
    messages:
        basename: i18n/messages
    mvc:
        favicon:
            enabled: false
    thymeleaf:
        mode: XHTML
    cloud:
        stream:
            bindings:
                fileOutput:
                    destination: file
                    binder: rabbitmqserver
                    contentType: application/x-java-serialized-object
                indexInput:
                    destination: index
                    binder: rabbitmqserver
                    contentType: application/x-java-serialized-object
            binders:
                rabbitmqserver:
                    type: rabbit
                    environment:
                        spring:
                            rabbitmq:
                                addresses: elephant.rmq.cloudamqp.com
                                username: username
                                password: password
                                virtual-host: virtualhost
```

can someone help me with this problem.

Comment: You don't seem to have any configuration for the rabbitmq server location.

Comment: i have on spring.cloud.binders property at my application.yml

Comment: Sorry; missed that; looks ok to me; no ideas then, sorry.

Comment: I have [added code to log the connection attempt](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-amqp/pull/681). After it's merged you could try with 1.7.5.BUILD-SNAPSHOT to see if it gives you any clues.

Comment: thx for your help, now i know that's my service was trying to connect to localhost message broker, because i forgot to excude RabbitAutoConfiguration class on my @EnableAutoConfiguration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed it,

Forgot to disable RabbitAutoConfiguration causing my service to connect localhost:5672 messagebroker server.

Fixed it by adding

```
@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude = {RabbitAutoConfiguration.class})
```

According from this page  https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream-binder-rabbit/blob/master/docs/src/main/asciidoc/overview.adoc, it's important to disable RabbitAutoConfiguration when using multiple binders on spring cloud stream app.

Answer (score 0):

Disable the rabbitmq management health check, I don't what it's doing but it's causing your problems:

`management.health.rabbit.enabled=false`

https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/common-application-properties.html